# Glassfish "Connection closed" error with a connection pool, JDBC, and SQL Server 2008

Tags: sql-server-2008, jdbc, glassfish, connection-pooling

When I try to do more than one transaction in a JSF page, I get the following error:

```
A potential connection leak detected for connection pool MSSQL. The stack trace of the thread is provided below : 
com.sun.enterprise.resource.pool.ConnectionPool.setResourceStateToBusy(ConnectionPool.java:324)
com.sun.enterprise.resource.pool.ConnectionPool.getResourceFromPool(ConnectionPool.java:758)
com.sun.enterprise.resource.pool.ConnectionPool.getUnenlistedResource(ConnectionPool.java:632)
com.sun.enterprise.resource.pool.AssocWithThreadResourcePool.getUnenlistedResource(AssocWithThreadResourcePool.java:196)
com.sun.enterprise.resource.pool.ConnectionPool.internalGetResource(ConnectionPool.java:526)
com.sun.enterprise.resource.pool.ConnectionPool.getResource(ConnectionPool.java:381)
com.sun.enterprise.resource.pool.PoolManagerImpl.getResourceFromPool(PoolManagerImpl.java:245)
com.sun.enterprise.resource.pool.PoolManagerImpl.getResource(PoolManagerImpl.java:170)
com.sun.enterprise.connectors.ConnectionManagerImpl.getResource(ConnectionManagerImpl.java:338)
com.sun.enterprise.connectors.ConnectionManagerImpl.internalGetConnection(ConnectionManagerImpl.java:301)
com.sun.enterprise.connectors.ConnectionManagerImpl.allocateConnection(ConnectionManagerImpl.java:190)
com.sun.enterprise.connectors.ConnectionManagerImpl.allocateConnection(ConnectionManagerImpl.java:165)
com.sun.enterprise.connectors.ConnectionManagerImpl.allocateConnection(ConnectionManagerImpl.java:160)
com.sun.gjc.spi.base.DataSource.getConnection(DataSource.java:113)
cl.codesin.colegios.util.persistencia.DAOManejador.abrir(DAOManejador.java:126)
```

Please notice the last line I pasted:

```
cl.codesin.colegios.util.persistencia.DAOManejador.abrir(DAOManejador.java:126)
```

`abrir` does the following:

```
public void abrir() throws SQLException {
    try
    {
        if(this.con==null || this.con.isClosed())
            this.con = fuenteDatos.getConnection();
    }
    catch(SQLException e)
    {
        throw e;
    }
}
```

It works in a singleton DAO manager this way: the DAO manager has one instance of each DAO and manages a single connection that every DAO shares. When a DAO is requested, it does the following:

```
public DAORegion getDAOregion() throws SQLException {
        try
        {
            if(con == null) //con is the connection the DAO manager uses
            {
                this.abrir();
            }
        }
        catch(SQLException e)
        {
            throw e;
        }
        if(this.DAOregion==null)
        {
            this.DAOregion = new DAORegion(this.con);
        }
        return DAOregion;
    }
```

When closing a connection, the manager just calls to `con.close()` without anything else.

By the way, I have no persistence.xml since I'm working with JDBC.

What am I doing wrong? Thank you beforehand.

EDIT: By desactivating the leak detection from the Glassfish server I could avoid the exception, however I'm still getting a "Connection closed" error. Worst is, now I don't know exactly where the error is being thrown.

EDIT 2: I changed my DAO manager again. Here's the implementation.

```
public class DAOManejador {

    public static DAOManejador getInstancia() {
        return DAOManejadorSingleton.INSTANCIA;
    }

    //This is just a sample, every getDAOXXX works the same.
    public DAOUsuario getDAOusuario() throws SQLException {
        try
        {
            if(con == null)
            {
                this.abrir();
            }
        }
        catch(SQLException e)
        {
            throw e;
        }
        if(this.DAOusuario==null)
        {
            this.DAOusuario = new DAOUsuario(this.con, this.stmt, this.res);
        }
        return DAOusuario;
    }

    public void abrir() throws SQLException {
        try
        {
            if(this.con==null || this.con.isClosed())
                this.con = fuenteDatos.getConnection();
        }
        catch(SQLException e)
        {
            throw e;
        }
    }

    public void iniciaTransaccion() throws SQLException {
        try
        {
            con.setAutoCommit(false);
        }
        catch(SQLException e)
        {
            throw e;
        }
    }

    public void cierraTransaccion()  throws SQLException {
        try
        {
            con.setAutoCommit(true);
        }
        catch(SQLException e)
        {
            throw e;
        }
    }

    public void comprometer() throws SQLException {
        try
        {
            con.commit();
        }
        catch(SQLException e)
        {
            throw e;
        }
    }

    public void deshacer() throws SQLException {
        try
        {
            con.rollback();
        }
        catch(SQLException e)
        {
            throw e;
        }
    }

    public void cerrar() throws SQLException {
        try
        {
            if(this.stmt!=null && !this.stmt.isClosed())
                stmt.close();

            if(this.res!=null && !this.res.isClosed())
                this.res.close();

            if(this.con!=null && !this.con.isClosed())
                con.close();
        }
        catch(SQLException e)
        {
            throw e;
        }
    }

    public void comprometerYTerminarTransaccion() throws SQLException {
        try
        {
            this.comprometer();
            this.cierraTransaccion();
        }
        catch(SQLException e)
        {
            throw e;
        }
    }

    public void comprometerYCerrarConexion() throws SQLException {
        try
        {
            this.comprometer();
            this.cierraTransaccion();
            this.cerrar();
        }
        catch(SQLException e)
        {
            throw e;
        }
    }

    //Protegidos
    @Override
    protected void finalize() throws SQLException, Throwable
    {
        try
        {
            this.cerrar();
        }
        finally
        {
            super.finalize();
        }
    }

    //Private
    private DataSource fuenteDatos;
    private Connection con = null;
    private PreparedStatement stmt = null;
    private ResultSet res = null;

    private DAOUsuario DAOusuario = null;
    private DAORegion DAOregion = null;
    private DAOProvincia DAOprovincia = null;
    private DAOComuna DAOcomuna = null;
    private DAOColegio DAOcolegio = null;

    private DAOManejador() throws Exception {
        try
        {
            InitialContext ctx = new InitialContext();
            this.fuenteDatos = (DataSource)ctx.lookup("jndi/MSSQL");
        }
        catch(Exception e){ throw e; }
    }

    private static class DAOManejadorSingleton {
        public static final DAOManejador INSTANCIA;
        static
        {
            DAOManejador dm;
            try
            {
                dm = new DAOManejador();
            }
            catch(Exception e)
            { dm=null; }
            INSTANCIA = dm;
        }
    }

}
```

What I did now is to provide a single access point for every DAO. When a DAO wants to use a statement or a resource, they'll all use the same one. When they need to open again one, the system does the following:

```
public abstract class DAOGenerico<T> {

    //Protected
    protected final String nombreTabla;
    protected Connection con;
    protected PreparedStatement stmt;
    protected ResultSet res;

    protected DAOGenerico(Connection con, PreparedStatement stmt, ResultSet res, String nombreTabla) {
        this.nombreTabla = nombreTabla;
        this.con = con;
        this.stmt = stmt;
        this.res = res;
    }

    //Prepares a query
    protected final void prepararConsulta(String query) throws SQLException 
    {            
        try
        {
            if(this.stmt!=null && !this.stmt.isClosed())
                this.stmt.close();
            this.stmt = this.con.prepareStatement(query);
        }
        catch(SQLException e){ throw e; }
    }

    //Gets a ResultSet
    protected final void obtenerResultados() throws SQLException {
        try
        {
            if(this.res!=null && !this.res.isClosed())
                this.res.close();
            this.res = this.stmt.executeQuery();
        }
        catch(SQLException e){ throw e; }
    }

}
```

And it *still* doesn't work.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

<strike>I tried not doing anything when closing the connection. I commented the code in the `cerrar` method, and for some reason, it works! Even when it's a bad practice! Is it okay to keep it like that, or should I find a way to close a connection?</strike>

Disregard this, I found what's wrong. I hope someone can make good use of this in the future.

## The problem

```
if(this.con==null || this.con.isClosed())
    this.con = fuenteDatos.getConnection();
```

Each time I try to open a connection, I get a **completely brand new** connection. What's the problem with this?

```
public DAOUsuario getDAOusuario() throws SQLException {
    try
    {
        if(con == null)
        {
            this.abrir();
        }
    }
    catch(SQLException e)
    {
        throw e;
    }
    if(this.DAOusuario==null)
    {
        this.DAOusuario = new DAOUsuario(this.con, this.stmt, this.res);
    }
    return DAOusuario;
}
```

Only when I create a new instance of the DAO I assign it a new connection. What will happen in the following case then?

```
DAOManejador daoManager = DAOManejador.getInstancia(); //Get an instance of the DAO manager
daoManager.abrir(); //Open the connection
DAOUsuario daoUser = daoManager.getDAOusuario(); //Get a DAOUsuario, a type of DAO. It'll have the same connection as the DAOManager, and it'll be stored in the instance of the DAO manager
... //Do database stuff
daoManager.cerrar(); //Close the connection
daoManager.abrir(); //Open the connection again. Note that this will be a new instance of the conection rather than the old one
```

If, from here, you try to do database stuff, you'll get a *Connection closed* error since `daoUser` will still hold the old connection.

## What I did

I modified the DAO manager class. It no longer has a `getDAOXXX()` per DAO, but rather the following:

```
public DAOGenerico getDAO(Tabla t) throws SQLException {
    try
    {
        if(con == null || this.con.isClosed())
        {
            this.abrir();
        }
    }
    catch(SQLException e)
    {
        throw e;
    }
    switch(t)
    {
        case REGION:
            return new DAORegion(this.con, this.stmt, this.res);
        case PROVINCIA:
            return new DAOProvincia(this.con, this.stmt, this.res);
        case COMUNA:
            return new DAOComuna(this.con, this.stmt, this.res);
        case USUARIO:
            return new DAOUsuario(this.con, this.stmt, this.res);
        case COLEGIO:
            return new DAOColegio(this.con, this.stmt, this.res);
        default:
            throw new SQLException("Se intentó vincular a una tabla que no existe.");
    }
}
```

Each time the user requests a DAO, it'll ask the manager to return the correct type of DAO. But instead of storing each instance, the manager will create new instances depending on the current connection (`con` is the connection, `stmt` is a PreparedStatement and `res` is a ResultSet - they will be used so they can be closed when the manager closes the connection so nothing leaks). `Tabla` is an `enum` holding the current table names in the database so it can return the correct DAO. This worked with no problems whatsoever. **The rest of the class is the same, so if you want to use it, just replace the `DAOUsuario` method with the one above and it should work fine**.